# How to ignore whitespace and punctuation?

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

I wrote a palindrome checker function and it works for the most part, but if the whitespace or punctuation isn't in the middle of the string it says it isn't a palindrome.

i.e

First test:

```
Enter string to test for palindrome:

hannah

string is a palindrome.
```

Second test:

```
Enter string to test for palindrome:

han nah

string is a palindrome.
```

Third test:

```
Enter string to test for palindrome:

hann.ah

string is not a palindrome.
```

Fourth test:

```
Enter string to test for palindrome:

han.nah

string is a palindrome.
```

I was wondering if there is a way to ignore the whitespace and punctuation all together so that `h.annah` or `hann ah` would be considered a palindrom?

Here's my code:

```
void isPalindrome (string s){  
    if(equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin()) )
        cout << "string is a palindrome. " << endl;
    else
        cout << "string is not a palindrome. " << endl;
}

int main(){
    string test1;
    cout << "Enter string to test for palindrome: " << endl;
    getline(cin, test1);

    isPalindrome(test1);

    string test2;
    cout << "Enter string to test for palindrome: " << endl;
    getline(cin, test2);

    isPalindrome(test2);

    string test3;
    cout << "Enter string to test for palindrome: " << endl;
    getline(cin, test3);

    isPalindrome(test3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should get in the habit of writing functions like `isPalindrome` in a fashion that returns `bool`, not one that produces output and gives no other  indication as to what it actually did. Additionally, arguments like that should be `const string& s` to avoid making rampant copies and to allow the compiler to optimize things better.

Comment: You also need to do some basic reading on how to write a simple `for` loop before your programs turn into endless tracts of cut-and-paste misery. Writing a loop that does something three times should be easy enough, and  more concise than what you have here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply a filter to the string prior to the palindrome check.

Here's one way.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void isPalindrome (std::string s){  
    if(equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin()) )
        std::cout << "string is a palindrome. " << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "string is not a palindrome. " << std::endl;
}

std::string remove_rubbish(std::string s)
{
    auto is_rubbish = [](char c) 
                { 
                    return std::ispunct(c) || std::isspace(c); 
                };

    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), 
                           s.end(), 
                           is_rubbish), 
            s.end());

    return s;    
}

int main(){
    auto s= std::string("ha-n.n?a h");
    isPalindrome(remove_rubbish(s));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped

Answer (score 0):

No problem! Just define algorithm `equal_if` that is not defined yet in the C++ Standard.:)

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

template <typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2, typename UnaryPredicate>
bool equal_if(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
              InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2,
              UnaryPredicate unary_predicate)
{
    do
    {
        while (first1 != last1 && !unary_predicate(*first1)) ++first1;
        while (first2 != last2 && !unary_predicate(*first2)) ++first2;
    } while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2 && *first1++ == *first2++);

    return first1 == last1 && first2 == last2;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s1("h.annah");
    std::string s2("hann ah");

    if (equal_if(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s1.rbegin(), s1.rend(), ::isalpha))
    {
        std::cout << "The string \"" << s1 << "\" is a palindrome" << std::endl;
    }

    if (equal_if(s2.begin(), s2.end(), s2.rbegin(), s2.rend(), ::isalpha))
    {
        std::cout << "The string \"" << s2 << "\" is a palindrome" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
The string "h.annah" is a palindrome
The string "hann ah" is a palindrome
```